# How to change the a value of a primary key of an entry to be inserted?

Tags: sql, triggers, h2

I am trying to do it with triggers, but my sql causes errors. I am not familiar with triggers, so I would appretiate if my code would be inspected. identificationnumber is the primary key of the table. And I need to change t bfeore inserting into the table. IS it possible with triggers?

```
CREATE
TRIGGER id_counter_trigger
ON newsletter_status
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    INSERT INTO newsletter_status (identificationnumber , bpid , consumer ,source ,vkorg , cryptid , status , regDat ,confirmDat , updateDat , deleteDat)
    SELECT  '44' + identificationnumber , bpid , consumer ,source ,vkorg , cryptid , status , regDat ,confirmDat , updateDat , deleteDat
    FROM inserted
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer may not be what you are looking for, but this is not the best use of a trigger.  My recommendation would be to let the database auto generate a primary key. Primary keys are extremely important and should never be changed. I then recommend you create a unique key for the value you are trying to create within your code and not do so using a trigger.  Triggers are intended to be used to update other tables, due to a change in data within a given table.

Comment: I understand that you are right. But suddenly there is a big obstacle to generate it in code. I need a woraround